# How to set image dynamically in android view

Tags: android

I have some 50 images which i want to display on view dynamically by picking images from drawable folder .how should i use them without making use of switch cases.

Comment: you can get images by their names from drawable folder

Comment: You could put their ids in an array and get them from there, you could use the `Resources.getIdentifier` method if their names have a pattern or you could use reflection if those drawables are all you have in the `drawable` folder.

Comment: you want the images to be dynamically displayed... but in which fashion... ?? like a slide show or someother?

Comment: @Luksprog Can you post an example code plz

Comment: @Pooja your question is not clear & completed.. Try to add code & more description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested to get image as a slide show showing all the images then you could simply use an integer array of all the images and next simply get the images using the array index.
You can use the link [click here](http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/image-slide-show.html) and you can show the image as a slide show (perhaps you need to do some modifications in that)

```
private void setImagesToFlipper(ViewFlipper flipper) {

  for (int count = 0; count < imageCountArray - 1; count++) {
   ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
   Bitmap  bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageCountArray[count]);
   imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
   flipper.addView(imageView);

  }
```

Where imageCountArray is something like this :

```
 int imageCountArray[] = {R.drawable.image0,R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2,R.drawable.image3,R.drawable.image4,};
```

and be sure that you are having images in your resources drawables folder

Edit :

or even you can use something like

```
String mDrawableName = "image1";
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
```

and use this id instead of the array

Hope this helps.Happy Coding

Comment: Its my pleasure. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically get the resource ID of a bundled drawable from your `Activity` subclass like this:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("my_image", "drawable", getPackageName());
```

assuming you have a **drawable** resource named `my_image.png`.

Then, just do:

```
myImageView.setImageResource(id);
```